# TypeScript unable to resolve function in Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

Hi I'm using Webstorm to develop a Vue.js application with TypeScript and have eslint with the ts-parser.

I have a Vue component (third party) assigned to a variable so that I can invoke functions on that component, the variable is using the component as it's type, however I get warnings in my IDE telling me that it's unable to resolve the method or functions I'm calling. They exist for sure as the code is working, what I'm trying to work out is how do I deal with this, it's not idea that the IDE can't resolve what I'm trying to do as I also can't use the autocomplete / suggestion functions of the IDE since it doesn't seem aware of the methods in the component.

TO try and give an example, in it's simplest case, if i do this in a Vue component:

```
myComponentVariable : Component | null = null;
myComponentVariable.doSomething()
```

I get a waring saying: "Unresolved function or method doSomething()"

The component does have a method "doSomething()" and the code works, but the IDE doesn't think it exists, or any method exists. The component is third party so I can't change it.

Is this an IDE issue that can be resolved or should I create TS Interfaces to use as types when referencing the components or what is best practice when dealing with this?

Thanks, Glen x

Comment: Hello Link19! it is not easy to recognize your situation can you add example code blocks to make it more clear.

Comment: @ThilinaLakshan I have tried, I'm finding it hard to articulate the issue or google about solutions too.

Comment: You are calling doSomething on null. This doesn't have anything to do with Typescript, would fail at runtime in JS as well (thus Webstorm complaining)

Comment: If the 3rd party library doesn't have any typings available, I'd use module augmentation to declare them myself. See module augmentation in the docs: (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: @v-moe that is simply an example to show the issue which occurs way before run time in the IDE. My actual code is obviously not calling a method on null, as i have said, it all run fine.

Comment: @steve16351 thanks, that looks like what I need, maybe I'm being thick here but how do you actually do it? There's no code examples of how I would merge an interface with a TS component and I can't import both in to my own Component when they have the same name?

Comment: What happens if you try `myComponentVariable?.doSomething()` or `(myComponentVariable as Component).doSomething()`? Not suggesting this is what you should do, just for diagnosis